# I am trying creating slide out menu in ios using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, slide, swrevealviewcontroller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController class]])
{
    SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController *swSegue=(SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController *)segue;
    swSegue.performBlock=^(SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController* rvc_seque,UIViewController* svc,UIViewController* dvc)
    {
        UINavigationController *nav=(UINavigationController *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        [nav setViewControllers:@[dvc] animated:NO];
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];
    };
}
```

}

I have created slide out menu in ios using xcode 6.4 and using 
SWRevealViewController Class.
I am writing above piece of code for navigation to desired view controller and but nothing happen there.Thanks

Comment: Please edit the formatting of your question!

Comment: Have you created segues of type SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController in interface builder?

Comment: no need of this code bro ,check that  are you set  the **Sw_rear** - for side menu  and **Sw_Front** for front menu

Comment: Thanks ..!  But  u r not getting my question..I have done with slide out menu and it sliding properly but i  want navigation  to a view controller on tableview cell selection but  there nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a breakpoint in your prepareForSegue method? Does it get called? When it gets called, what's the class of the segue? That would be the first thing you check, and without knowing the answer it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you.! Yes i have set breakpoint at prepareForSegue method and it gets called .What will be the next procees i should do to get expected output